Creating a large thin-walled hollow cylinder/tube
I'm looking to create something like this:

Structurally very simple, but the second point is stumping me, I don't know how to DIY it.

Some material (wood maybe) cut into a circle. (5ft diameter)

2. Some material (???) bent into the edge of this structure (length=perimeter of the 5ft dia above)

A dry plant in front

The second point in bold is what I need help with. How can I make a circular edge like this? I'm not very sure wood can be bent like this, so what material would be best, with what technique?
Would love some of your expertise.

Wood can be very easily bent using steam. If you'll wander over to [woodworking.se], you'll find several questions there about it, and you can do some searching on the internet to find out what's involved. Note, that with a diameter of 60 inches, the circumference of the circle is ~188 inches. That's over 15' 6" - you're going to need to make your edge banding in sections...

There are all kinds of thermoplastics out there.  IMO your biggest issue will be finding the 5' dia. circle, if you want a monolithic circle—plywood comes in 4x8.  You may have to put up with two pieces glued together.

Also note that this is going to be heavy, especially if made out of wood.

You could also just cut the circle and paint the rim-shadow effect onto it, though you would lose having the shadow change with direction and quality of lighting.

In addition to the wood bending techniques already mentioned, there's another approach.  Very thin strips of wood bend easily, and gluing several thin layers together while bent around a form will give you a strong curved piece.  It won't take many layers based on the picture you included - the curved piece doesn't look more an 1/4 inch thick or so.  There are many examples on the internet of how to make laminated curved wood.

Wood can be bent.
Check out steaming as one possibility.
Another is to place many small sawcuts close together on the interior surface to permit the bend. The depth and width will affect the curve of the bend - more cuts close together means a tighter bend.
As for making the circle shape, a pin, string and pencil should give you the line. Then cut and smooth.

There is also "bending plywood" made for the blowing curves, though you might need to layer/laminate it to get the thickness you want.
